# how to decode error code in spring boot fiegn client

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-feign, netflix-feign, feign

I have to implement a error decode for feign client I went to through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46662265/feign-client-error-handling) link 
 in that, decode function needs response but how to get this response from fiegn client, below is my feign client.

```
@FeignClient(name="userservice")
public interface UserClient {

    @RequestMapping(
            method= RequestMethod.GET,
                      path = "/userlist")
    String getUserByid(@RequestParam(value ="id") String id);

}
```

I call feign client like this, whenever there is a error FeignException will be caught, but I want to get the proper error codes, like 400, 403 etc .

```
try {
    String str = userClient.getUserByid(id);
    return str;
    }

catch(FeignException e)
 {
 logger.error("Failed to get user", id);
}

catch (Exception e) 
{
 logger.error("Failed to get user", id);
}
```

Comment: check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48441738/feignclient-throws-instead-of-returning-responseentity-with-error-http-status

Comment: The `FeignException` has a `status` field which contains the actual response status.