# Resilience4J Circuit Breaker to kick-in on specific HTTP status code

Tags: java, http-status-codes, feign, circuit-breaker, resilience4j

I am aware we can use `recordExceptions()` while building `CircuitBreakerConfig` to register exceptions on which Circuit Breaker should transition to `OPEN` state.

#### Code

I am using `resilience4j-feign` to decorate my `CircuitBreaker`. Would be really helpful if you can point me to a code example.

#### Question

How to make the Circuit Breaker kick-in in case of a **specific HTTP status code** (e.g. on [503 Service Unavailable](https://httpstatuses.com/503)) ?

Comment: Yes, but then you need to have those http errors represented in an Exception class; you own or from a standard http library. What http framework are you using?

Comment: @Jocke I do have a CustomExceptionClass that possess status code. How should we customize the circuit breaker config based on the  status code from the custom exception class?

Answer (score 4):

You need to write an Exception/Response handler to your client's external calls and throw custom exceptions based on http status received. Then register these exceptions as record exceptions in your circuit breaker config. Following is a small example. The CB will be open only on AbcException. The CB config is`resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.bookService.record-exceptions=com.sk.example.cb.circuitbreakerr4j.AbcException`

```js
@Service
@Slf4j
public class BookApiService {
  RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
  @CircuitBreaker(name = "bookService", fallbackMethod = "getBookFallback")
  public String getBook(){
    try {
      ResponseEntity<String> stringResponseEntity = restTemplate.getForEntity(new URI("http://localhost:8080/book"), String.class);
      if(null != stringResponseEntity){
        if(stringResponseEntity.getStatusCode().is2xxSuccessful()){
          return stringResponseEntity.getBody();
        }
      }
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (HttpServerErrorException e){
      log.error("Service unavailable",e);
      if(e.getMessage().startsWith("503")) {
        throw new AbcException();
      }else{
        throw e;
      }
    }
    return "";
  }
```

Comment: Is there any way that we can open circuit breaker based on the status code. I see method like recordException() or recordFailurePredicate() accepts a predicate of class java.lang.Throwable. Will it be possible to get the status from the throwable and make a predicate?

Answer (score 3):

From the docs, [Create and configure a CircuitBreaker](https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/circuitbreaker#create-and-configure-a-circuitbreaker):

```
// Create a custom configuration for a CircuitBreaker
CircuitBreakerConfig circuitBreakerConfig = CircuitBreakerConfig.custom()
  .recordExceptions(IOException.class, TimeoutException.class) // add you exceptions here!!!
  .ignoreExceptions(BusinessException.class, OtherBusinessException.class)
  .build();
```

> A list of exceptions that are recorded as a failure and thus increase
> the failure rate. Any exception matching or inheriting from one of the
> list counts as a failure, unless explicitly ignored via
> ignoreExceptions.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR:** use a custom exception that communicates HTTP status (e.g. 503) from HTTP client (e.g. Feign) to Resilience4J

1. Feign: **implement and configure** an `ErrorDecoder`  to throw a **custom exception** on HTTP status like 503
2. Resilience4J: **record** that custom exception using Circuit Breaker config.

### Feign

Feign by default throws a `FeignException` in case of an erroneous HTTP status code. You can get the status code number via method [int status()](https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign/blob/master/core/src/main/java/feign/FeignException.java#L110).

To customize your feign-clients error-handling configure a (custom) implementation of [`ErrorDecoder`](https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign#error-handling)

> If you need more control over handling unexpected responses, Feign instances can register a custom `ErrorDecoder` via the builder.
> [..]
> All responses that result in an HTTP status **not in the 2xx range** will trigger the `ErrorDecoder`'s decode method, allowing you to handle the response, wrap the failure into a custom exception or perform any additional processing. If you want to retry the request again, throw a `RetryableException`. This will invoke the registered `Retryer`.

#### Customize Feign error-handling

Implement and configure a custom `ErrorDecoder` to throw an exception in case of HTTP status 503.

```java
@Component
@Slf4j
public class CustomErrorDecoder implements ErrorDecoder {
    
    @Override
    public Exception decode(String methodKey, Response response) {
        
        switch (response.status()) {
            case 400:
                log.error("Status code {} on methodKey '{}'", response.status(), methodKey);
            case 503:
                return new ServiceUnavailableException("HTTP status 503 when calling " methodKey);
            default:
                return new Exception(response.reason());
        } 
    }
    
}
```

This will then throw your custom exception `ServiceUnavailableException`.

### Resilienc4J's CircuitBreaker

By default the circuit-breaker reacts on exceptions. It records them and will open the circuit if there are too much in too less time.

You can configure, which Exceptions to record and which to ignore as expected on the business-level.

#### Trigger CircuitBreaker on specific exceptions

You can configure CiruitBreaker to **record that exception**. [Joke's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60862930/5730279) explains how to do that.

### See also

- [spring feign client exception handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55020389/spring-feign-client-exception-handling)
- [Feign Client Error Handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46662265/feign-client-error-handling)
- Apps Developer Blog: [Feign Error Handling with ErrorDecoder](https://www.appsdeveloperblog.com/feign-error-handling-with-errordecoder/)
- Resilience4J docs: [Feign, Decorating Feign Interfaces](https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/feign#decorating-feign-interfaces)